# mingw make fail by shell = cmd.exe

Tags: makefile, mingw

I compile `phyx4.1` android build on `win10` with `mingw` and failed.

After some hours research, I find this line `SHELL = cmd.exe` which make the behaviour stranger.

My makefile is like:

```
SHELL = cmd.exe
help:
echo hahaha
echo gagagaga
exit
```

I try to execute it by `mingw` command line

```
make help
```

but it enter cmd.exe and not return. anyone know why?

ps: finally, i found the solution, use mingw32-make.exe rather than make.exe ..thanks for your replays

Answer (score 1):

`GNU make` passes `-c` to $(SHELL) to execute a command.

When you have a command like `echo hahaha`, `make` tries to run

```
cmd.exe -c echo hahaha
```

as `cmd.exe` does not recognize `-c echo hahaha`, it went into interactive session.

To make it work, you can do :

```
SHELL = cmd.exe
.SHELLFLAGS = /c
help:
    echo hahaha
    echo gagagaga
    exit
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it works. i try it with mingw+msys and fail, but can work on msys2.

Answer (score 0):

The `SHELL` variable designates the command interpreter with which `make` should execute rules' recipes.  For most `make` implementations it defaults to one or another variation on the Bourne shell, such as `Bash`.  This is important, because it has a deep and pervasive impact on the effects of running recipes.

Different shells are not interchangeable.  Different Bourne-family shells are often similar enough that they will not exhibit different behavior for the recipes in a given makefile, but `cmd.exe` is an another beast altogether.  Trying to use `cmd.exe` as the shell for a makefile written with a Bourne shell in mind (as most are) is a recipe for disaster.

> i try to execute it by mingw command line
>
> ```
> make help
> ```
>
> but it enter cmd.exe and not return anyone know why?

It seems likely that the issue revolves around the use of the `exit` command in the recipe, which appears completely pointless.  It is possible, however, that `cmd.exe` just doesn't work at all with your particular `make`.  The details don't really matter because overall, this is a knob that you generally should not twiddle.  You especially should not turn it to the `cmd.exe` setting unless you are the makefile author and you know exactly what you are doing.